# What is better for selling a car, inspection by dealer or highly rated local mechanic?

Tags: inspection, dealer, selling

I am selling a car and will get the car inspected and provide the inspection results to future potential buyers.

**What is better for selling a car, inspection by dealer or highly rated local mechanic?**

It seems likely that even if the local mechanic does a better job on the inspection the buyer may trust a dealer more. This is my first time selling and so I'm not sure.

Comment: Commercial advice is off-topic, and depending on your locality/circumstances one party may be more favourable than the other. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

Any inspection gives prominence to the vehicle and confidence to the seller provided it's done by somewhere seen as reputable, which does obviously include the dealership network.

Check your local automobile club, by which I mean the types of organisation that provide breakdown cover and recovery services such as the RAC, AAA, etc...  These typically have an accredited inspection service delivered through their network which will carry the kind of providence that a buyer would be looking for.  As an example, in the UK the RAC offer such a service - [details here](http://www.rac.co.uk/buying-a-car/vehicle-inspections)

The risk you run using a local mechanic, unless they are part of a recognised service network the likes of Bosch or Halfords in the UK, is that a buyer will be suspicious because they may think you have a personal relationship with the mechanic.

Comment: In the US what accreditation would be equivalent? ASE master?